# Mark value range in dotplot

Tags: r, lattice

I have the following data frame

```
   ds <- data.frame(iso2c=as.factor(c(rep("AR",3),rep("BR",3),rep("DE",3),rep("US",3))),

             region= as.factor(c(rep("LATAM",6),rep("DEVELOPED",6))),

             year= rep(c(1979,1989,1999),4),

             value= c( 47.0 , 28.6,  20.8, 100.0,  64.2,  35.4,  16.0 ,  9.0,   5.5,  15.6,  11.6,   8.6))                 )
```

and would like to plot the data in a dotplot, as follows,

```
  library(lattice)
  dotplot(iso2c~value, data=ds, groups=year,pch=19,col="dark blue",cex=1.3,ylab="country")
```

I would like to plot a line for each country across the whole range of values (from countrie's max to countries's min). I cannot use "type=h" because it would plot the line from max to zero, not from max to min. 
Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does it. I calculated the max and min of the x-values within groups of the "y" values, and then used the lattice-`lsegments` functions

```
dotplot(iso2c~value, groups=year, data=ds, panel = function(x,y,...) { 
                           x0=sapply( split(x,y), min)
                           y0=as.numeric(unique(y) )+.1
                           x1=sapply( split(x,y) ,max)
                           y1=as.numeric(unique(y)) +.1
           panel.dotplot(x, y,...)
           lsegments(x0,y0,x1,y1)
                           } ,
       pch=19,col="dark blue",cex=1.3,ylab="country")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, works perfectly, i just added the "..." parameter to the panel function and the invocation to panel.dotplot.

Comment: Good idea. The difficult aspect for me, that only came to me after many failed efforts, was getting the data for the segment endpoints arranged properly. I had been trying to do it within the delivery of values to the arguments, but only achieved success when I tried doing it before calling `lsegments`. Using 'subscripts' or 'groups'  doesn't work because there really is only one group of subscripts and the points are all being plotted within a single panel.